# "potential rewrite attack" message on Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, security

When I was sending Ether using Mist I got the following message on Geth.

```
I0528 18:34:57.312997 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 3 txs in 19.344963ms. #1602638 [e4523f86 / e4523f86]
I0528 18:35:24.519128 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1091] Peer ############ [headers 0.00/s, blocks 0.00/s, receipts 0.00/s, states 0.00/s, lacking    0]: potential rewrite attack: #0 [########…] <= #1512638 limit
```

After that, the transaction didn't get sent. And I had to send it again.

What does the message mean? Is it dangerous? Is it Geth and the accounts currently being used on Mist compromised?

I tried Googling but nothing really relevant showed up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the message appears 4 times [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/fc0638f9d86fe8c0917c82cf32f548bb1953bfe9/eth/downloader/downloader.go) in the geth code of this function
The comment explains it well :

```
// findAncestor61 tries to locate the common ancestor block of the local chain and
// a remote peers blockchain. In the general case when our node was in sync and
// on the correct chain, checking the top N blocks should already get us a match.
// In the rare scenario when we ended up on a long reorganisation (i.e. none of
// the head blocks match), we do a binary search to find the common ancestor.
func (d *Downloader) findAncestor61(p *peer, height uint64) (uint64, error) {
    glog.V(logger.Debug).Infof("%v: looking for common ancestor", p)

    // Figure out the valid ancestor range to prevent rewrite attacks
```

You're not compromised, it works as intended

Comment: It makes sense since the message only appeared once. So in short, was this a rare case where Geth did a binary search because the head blocks didn't match?

Comment: honeslty I don't know, I don't keep logs so can't comment on that

Answer (score 2):

When the last block mined corresponds with the last block available (see https://testnet.etherscan.io/). If you execute your node with "console" at the end, then you could write "eth.syncing" in the console to see information about the syncing process, for example:

```
> eth.syncing

{
   startingBlock: 300,
   currentBlock: 312,
   highestBlock: 512
}
```

In you case, you last block mined when you wrote this post was #1805595 and the last block available according to etherscan is #1805643, so you are already synced.

About the potential rewrite attack, see: ["potential rewrite attack" message on Geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4401/potential-rewrite-attack-message-on-geth)

Answer (score 2):

To check if the blocks are synced use `eth.syncing`(as indicated in the answer before) or `eth.blockNumber`

but for the **rewrite attack** :
I think you are connected to a peer who is trying to give you blocks from the other chain (Forked one) so update your geth or just restart it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have some blocks from Morden in your datadir.

the default `datadir` is:

```
Mac: ~/Library/Ethereum
Linux: ~/.ethereum
Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum
```

Delete the `chaindata` subdirectory that you find.

Then download Ropsten genesis block file from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4270001/testnet_genesis.json)

and run `geth --datadir /path/to/testnet/data init genesis.json; geth --datadir /path/to/testnet/data --networkid 3 console`