# Syncing ethereum testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, ropsten

I'm syncing my `geth` client with `ropsten` testnet and just realized how slow is the syncing process after a certain block(trying to retrieve information from blocks that got in blockchain yesterday) for a couple of hours.

Basically I got several messages like this one, saying a potential rewrite attack:

```
I0111 08:28:09.783928 eth/downloader/downloader.go:723] Peer 7335842dc6658f60 [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 13.155759485s]: potential rewrite attack: #224778 [00000000�] <= #224778 limit
```

My question differs from this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4401/potential-rewrite-attack-message-on-geth) as I'm not yet synced as I've checked out. One of the answers there doesn't apply here as I made sure I referenced the `ropsten` genesis block and checked the hash of that genesis block in my local database to certify I'm running to get in sync with the right network. So, I don't believe the cause of this high delay in my node syncing process isn't actually the addition of old `morden` to my local database.

Is this behavior expected when syncing? Is there any way to maximize the peer coverage to speed up the whole process if comes to that?

Comment: @5chdn please check my new edition, my question is similar to the one you referenced but I believe my context is different from what I've noticed as solution to that question.

Comment: There is probably a consensus issue between the clients on testnet, that happens sometimes.

Comment: What do you get if you type `eth.syncing` ?

Comment: @SauloRicci check [this regarding the consensus issues on ropsten](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/11334/87).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--fast` flag.The fast flag enables fast syncing through state downloads rather than downloading the full block data.

Another flag that can be used along with `--fast` to sync your client more quickly is `--cache`. The Cache flag can be used to change the default alloted memory for a fast sync.

```
   geth --datadir /path/to/testnet/data --networkid=3 –-syncmode=fast –-cache=1024
```

Refer this :- https://medium.com/@crissimrobert/a-guide-to-ropsten-testnet-setup-f8952d615417

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "-- fast" flag in your geth command at the time of syncing. 
--fast is default if you start geth the first time with no blocks downloaded. If you restart geth after initial start, --fast doesn't work anymore (it only works starting from scratch). That's why you'll have to explicitly mention it.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see everywhere on the internet there are many issues with Geth syncing with Ropsten. I strongly recommend using Parity to sync with Ropsten network. For that I recommend following one of those links:

- [How To Sync Entire Ethereum Client in 2-3 hours for Testnets &
  Mainnet](https://www.blockchain-council.org/blockchain/how-to-sync-entire-ethereum-client-in-2-3-hours-for-testnet-mainnet-parity/)
- Or: [Ethereum Parity fast sync for Ropsten testnet](http://www.ziggify.com/blog/ethereum-parity-fast-setup-ropsten-testnet/)

In addition to be easy to configure & fast to sync, Parity has a very rich command line parameters. You can check them at: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Configuring-Parity